# Replacing Pattern Matches in a String kept as value of a key in JSON

Tags: regex, json, string, angularjs, replace

I have a JSON file that has a key value pairs as shown below

```
{
    "parameters": "<FieldLabel Type='Something'><Label><![CDATA[Click on this number to initiate call <a href='tel:123456' parameter='DialMe,100.200.3000'>100.200.3000'>100.200.3000'>100.200.3000'>tel:1002003000'>100.200.3000</a> or<a href='tel:911'parameter='dial911,911'>911'>911'>911'>tel:911'>911</a>  ]]></Label><Description><![CDATA[]]></Description></FieldLabel>"
 }
```

I want to replace

```
parameter='DialMe,100.200.3000' with my-url-click='DialMe,null,null,100.200.3000'
```

and

```
parameter='dial911,911' with my-url-click='dial911,null,null,911'
```

before I can render it on as HTML using Angular's ng-bind-html and $sce.trustAsHtml.
The catch is the JSON has many such key value pairs and each of them has different values for the parameter like  `parameter=dial108,108`.So normal string replacement is not possible.How shall I do it for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "<FieldLabel Type='Something'><Label><![CDATA[Click on this number to initiate call <a href='tel:123456' parameter='DialMe,100.200.3000'>100.200.3000'>100.200.3000'>100.200.3000'>tel:1002003000'>100.200.3000</a> or<a href='tel:911'parameter='dial911,911'>911'>911'>911'>tel:911'>911</a>  ]]></Label><Description><![CDATA[]]></Description></FieldLabel>";

str = str.replace(/parameter=\'.*,/g, function(s){
    return s.replace("parameter", "my-url-click") + "null,null,"
});
```